# Assembly Code and Switch Statement Cases

Tags: c, assembly, switch-statement, jump-table

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how the cases 50, 52, etc were determined through the assembly language.

From what I understand, the jump table corresponds to the actions to do in each case and that the check that edx > 5 means that the case ranges from 0 to 5? I believe 1 is left out because it is the default case, but why is 5 left out?

I feel like there should be a case 55: where result *= result, no?

If anyone could help explain, that would be great. Thank you!

> ```
> int switch_prob(int x) 
> {
>     int result = x;
>     switch (x)
>     {
>         case 50:
>         case 52:
>             result <<= 2;
>             break;
>         case 53:
>             result >>= 2;
>             break;
>         case 54:
>             result *= 3;
>             break;
>         default:
>             result += 10;   
>     }
>     return result;
> }
> ```
>
> Figure 3.38 shows the disassembled object code for the procedure. We are only
>       interested in the part of the code shown on lines 4 through 16. We can see on line 4 that
>       parameter x (at offset 8 relative to %ebp) is loaded into register %eax, corresponding to
>       program variable result. The “lea 0x0(%esi), %esi” instruction on line 11 is a nop
>       instruction inserted to make the instruction on line 12 start on an address that is a
>       multiple of 16
>
> The jump table resides in a different area of memory. Using the debugger GDB,
>       we can examine the six 4-byte words of memory starting at address 0x8048468 with the
>       command x/6w 0x8048468. GDB prints the following:
>
> ```
> (gdb) x/6w
> 0x8048468: 0x080483d5 0x080483eb 0x080483d5 0x0x80483e0
> 0x8048478: 0x080483e5 0x080483e8
> (gdb)
> ```
>
> Assembly Code:
>
> ```
> 1: 080483c0 <switch_prob>:
> 2: 80483c0: push %ebp
> 3: 80483c1: mov %esp,%ebp
> 4: 80483c3: mov 0x8(%ebp),%eax // X is copied into eax ; eax = x
> 5: 80483c6: lea 0xffffffce(%eax),%edx // placeholder 
> 6: 80483c9: cmp $0x5, %edx // Compare edx (3rd argument) with 5; Edx - 5 // clearly, edx is x
> 7: 80483cc: ja 80483eb <switch_prob+0x2b> // if edx - 5 > 0, Jump into line 16 (default)
> 8: 80483ce: jmp *0x8048468(,%edx,4) // Go into the jump table
> 9: 80483d5: shl $0x2, %eax // eax << 2
> 10: 80483d8: jmp 80483ee <switch_prob+0x2e> // Jump to line 17
> 11: 80483da: lea 0x0(%esi),%esi // esi = esi  NOP. Filling in N bytes
> 12: 80483e0: sar $0x2, %eax // eax >> 2
> 13: 80483e3: jmp 80483ee <switch_prob+0x2e> // Jump to line 17
> 14: 80483e5: lea (%eax, %eax, 2), %eax // eax = eax + 2(eax)
> 15: 80483e8: imul %eax, %eax // eax *= eax
> 16: 80483eb: add $0xa, %eax // eax += 10
> 17: 80483ee: mov %ebp, %esp // esp = ebp
> 18: 80483f0: pop %ebp
> 19: 80483f1: ret
> ```

Comment: Well you do have five cases in the switch.

Comment: Shouldn't I have 6 since Case 5 corresponds to 0x80483e8? @JoachimPileborg

Comment: Zero-based counting, from `0` to `5` (inclusive) there are six numbers. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg. Yeah, but from my example the only ones are 50, 52, 53, 54, and 51 for default. It's missing 55? Or is that absorbed into 54

Comment: @Crowning What do you mean by 55? There doesn't seem to be a Case 55 in your switch statement.

Comment: As you are probably aware `lea 0xffffffce(%eax),%edx` effectively adds -50(decimal) to eax (variable x) and stores it in edx (edx=-50+x).

Answer (score 4):

The assembly does not match the source code. It matches something more like this:

```
int switch_prob(int x) 
{
    int result = x;
    switch (x)
    {
        case 50:
        case 52:
            result <<= 2;
            break;
        case 53:
            result >>= 2;
            break;
        case 54:
            result *= 3;
            // WARNING: Falls through
        case 55:
            result *= result;
            // WARNING: Falls through
        default:
            result += 10;   
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is likely caused by human error (e.g. updating the source code in the question so it's not identical to the question last year's students got, but forgetting to update the assembly to match).

Never assume teachers/professors are non-human...

Comment: I'd agree human error, sounds like the answer that was provided was incorrect (the answer was probably based on a similar exercise from a previous semester and not properly updated)

Comment: Thank you! This makes much more sense. The problem was from a Harvard assignment too Lol